# Hooking a callback into the code within a Gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor, callbacks

I want to run some JavaScript when a user uploads an image or images using the `core/image` block or `core/gallery` block. Ideally I would run my own code when the [`onSelectImage`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/a615ce6862545360ce6a463a5a7a5a17f71711f4/packages/block-library/src/image/edit.js#L171) function is called (and the equivalent for `core/gallery`). I've looked at hooks in Gutenberg but it seems that they're only available in a [small number of places](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/), and there are none directly for the `core/image` or `core/gallery` blocks.

I know the developers intend to make it easy to apply actions and filters in Gutenberg, but I'm not sure if they just haven't added any hooks/filters for the `core/image` block yet or if it's already possible but I'm not seeing how to do it.